# Why is the time always wrong on my ipad?

Tags: ipad

On my ipad (gen1, 3g, iOS4.3.3) the time is constantly 5-15 mins fast (depending on whether I set it manually or automatically). I don't have the same issue on my iphone 4 and don't recall having it on my iphone 3G either.

Anyone know why this happens and what the fix for it is?

Note: I've tried changing the settings from automatic to manual, and synching with my Mac (which has the right time). Also, setting to automatic actually results in the time being 15 mins fast instead of 5!

Comment: is a sim card inserted into the device?

Comment: yes, and it's connected to wifi. even has an active data plan.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem all the time on my original iPad 3G (with sim but without data plan) running iOS 4. Once I updated the iPad to iOS 5, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this is quite an old one, the iOS version originally supplied with the iPad did not support automatically updating the date/time based on location, not even on the 3G version.

however with the introduction of iOS5, it was added for all iPad versions.